# Replace character in pig in HDInsight using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight

My data is in the following format..

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":"{\"QuuxId\":1234,\"QuuxName\":\"Sam\"}"}
```

I need it to be in this format:

```
{"Foo":"ABC","Bar":"20090101100000","Quux":{"QuuxId":1234,"QuuxName":"Sam"}}
```

I'm trying to using Pig's replace function to get it in the format I need..
So, I tried [as in here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-pig-powershell/)..

```
#Specify the cluster name
$clusterName = "CLUSTERNAME"
#Where the output will be saved
$statusFolder = "/tutorial/pig/status"

#Store the Pig Latin into $QueryString
$QueryString =  "LOGS = LOAD 'wasb:///example/data/sample.log'as unparsedString:chararray;" +
"REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE($0, '"\\{', '\\{');"
...and so on..
```

I receive an error at the second line (REPL1 =...)
Unexpected token '\\' in expression or statement.

Now this code works perfectly well when I run it using remote desktop

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: escape the `"` as `\`"` or `""`. You'll probably need to replace `$0` as `\`$0` as well

Answer (score 0):

I assume you attempt to store the following string value in the variable:

```
REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE($0, '"\\{', '\\{');
```

The first "interpretation" of your string is by the PowerShell parser. Since you use double-quotes (`"`), it's treated as an expandable string.

Since you don't escape the `"` inside the `REPLACE()` statement, the parser assumes that the string stops there.

What you're left with is:

```
"REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE(, '"
# a valid string, $0 expanded to an empty string
\\
# two slashes , PowerShell cannot resolve these to anything meaningful
{
# opening curly brace
', '
# a valid string literal
\\
# two slashes , PowerShell still cannot resolve these to anything meaningful
{
# opening curly brace
');"
# non-terminated string
```

You need to escape the `"` inside `REPLACE()`, either by using a two double-quotes in succession (`""`), or use the backtick escape sequence (`\`"`):

```
$QueryString += "REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE($0, '`"\\{', '\\{');"
```

or

```
$QueryString += "REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE($0, '""\\{', '\\{');"
```

Your might also want to escape `$0`, to avoid string expansion:

```
$QueryString += "REPL1 = foreach LOGS REPLACE(`$0, '""\\{', '\\{');"
```

Comment: New error:  Start-AzureHDInsightJob : Request failed with code:BadRequest
Content:{"error":"Passed in parameter is incorrectly quoted: LOGS = LOAD
'wasb://mycontainer@myns.blob.core.windows.net/pigdatauax/' as unparsedString:chararray;REPL1c = foreach LOGS
GENERATE REPLACE($0, '\"\\\\{', '\\\\{');"}
At line:1 char:11
          
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-AzureHDInsightJob], HttpLayerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.WebRequest.HttpLayerE